# Array por bloques PHP

Tags: php, laravel

¿Como puedo hacer para que este foreach me muestre bloques de 4 unidades?

```
 <div class="item active">
    @foreach($stores as $stores)
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/img/company/{{$stores->image}}">
      </div>
    @endforeach
 </div
```

Cuando este carrusel corre, muestra una sola imagen al tiempo. lo que quiero es que muestre amenos 4 imágenes por cada pasada sin que se repita 4 veces la misma imagen.

¿como puedo lograrlo?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco más que es lo que necesitas? Un ejemplo de lo que estas obteniendo con tu prueba y de lo que te gustaría obtener, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi respuesta es parecida a la Luis Cabrero, pero si $stores es una Collection de Laravel, puedes usar el método chunk para partirla en trozos de 4.

De esta manera con dos foreachs recorres los grupos de 4 y para cada uno las imágenes.

Así tendrás N item con hasta 4 imagenes cada uno. El último grupo puede que tenga menos dependiendo del tamaño de tu colección.

Si tienen que ser grupos de 4 puedes usar @if($stores->count() != 4) para controlar este caso.

```
<div class="item active">
    @php
        $gruposDe4 = $stores->chunk(4);
    @endphp
    @foreach($gruposDe4 as $stores)
      <div class="item">
      @foreach($stores as $stores)
          <img src="/img/company/{{$stores->image}}">
      @endforeach
      </div>
    @endforeach
 </div>
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto. Pero tuve que cambiar esta línea: `$gruposDe4 = $stores->chunk(4);` por esta :`$gruposDe4 = (array_chunk($stores, 4));` con eso funciona perfecto

Comment: El uso de **`@`** es una práctica no recomendada en PHP.

Comment: @A.Cedano las `@` que están en esta respuesta son "correctas", pues forman parte de la sintaxis de Blade, el motor de templating de Laravel.

Comment: @Pepote No es una buena práctica hacer el `chunk` en la vista, no forma parte de dicha capa pues es "business logic".

Comment: Ok entendido. No lo sabía. No uso Laravel. Gracias por el dato @Shaz

Comment: @Shaz gracias por el apunte, pero para la respuesta creo que es más fácil de explicar así.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes en el array `$stores` un número de elementos módulo 4 el código sería el siguiente. Eso sí, si no, los %4 restantes quedarían fuera en la última iteración del bucle. Se puede posteriormente comprobar que `count($stores)%4` es 0, y si no lo es, coger los últimos elementos del array.

```
<div class="item active">
    @for($i = 0; $i < count($stores); $i+4)
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/img/company/{{$stores[$i]->image}}">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/img/company/{{$stores[$i+1]->image}}">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/img/company/{{$stores[$i+2]->image}}">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="/img/company/{{$stores[$i+3]->image}}">
      </div>
    @endfor
    <!-- Si count($stores)%4 != 0 -->
    @if(count($stores)%4 != 0)
      <?php $mod = count(%stores)%4;?>
      @for($j = $mod; $j > 0; $j++)
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/img/company/{{$stores[count($stores) - $j]->image}}">
        </div>
      @endfor
    @endif
 </div>
```

No estoy muy familiarizado con `laravel` pero bueno, espero que te ayude, más o menos la idea sería esa. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Por alguna razón no funciona con esta solución, lo raro es que obtengo un bloqueo y no puedo ver que es lo que falla.